# Ionic2 open other Ionic2 app via yourapp:// then froze

Tags: ionic2

Hi I have been using Ionic2 (App A) to call other Ionic2 App (App B) to via `<a href="otherapp://>` It could be call successfully sometime but most of the time it stuck at loading page.

My current solution is instead of App A Called App B I use App B Call app A then let App A call back to App B but is there a better way to solve this solution

here is video of how it's look like when stuck
https://youtu.be/jeaggXPkZjI

Answer (score 0):

Please check below attached plugin, its better to use - [Custom-URL-scheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme)

Also you can use deep linking plugin from ionic 2 
https://blog.ionicframework.com/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/